# Can't get Meteor cloudinary package to work

Tags: meteor, package, cloudinary

I am working on a Windows machine with Meteor 0.8.1, and I am trying to get the cloudinary package (from git user Lepozepo) to work.  I reverted the package to a version prior to the Meteor 0.9 changes to package handling, so it should be compatible with the version of Meteor that I am using.  I followed the readme, and things appear to work on the client side.  But when it tries to call the server method - I've tried both 'cloudinary_upload' and 'cloudinary_upload_stream' - the server throws an error: Exception while invoking method 'cloudinary_upload' undefined

The method is clearly defined in the server.js file. I've verified that the package is installed.  I have no idea why meteor can't seem to find this method, and worse, I have no idea how to troubleshoot it.

Comment: For the record, I screwed up the server configuration.  The package works great when used correctly!

Comment: I just added the server config variable to a startup function on the server side. Not sure if that'll help your situation.